# how to scrape a page with javascript effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, web-scraping

I am new to web scraping and so far I only know how to scrape basic html page using python beautiful soup. What I want is to extract the information on this [page](http://insightdatascience.com/fellows). Specifically, I would like to get the following data from all the fellows (around 700 of them)

- name
- background
- insight project
- current employer

However, that page is rendered by javascript and the desired information only show up as a separate box when mouseover event is triggered on each fellows picture.

How to extract text in this case? Any information (books, web resources) is appreciated. Python solutions are preferred if possible. Many thanks.

Comment: I disabled JavaScript on the site, and the tool-tips still show. The content is there, it's just hidden via CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the page source of the website.

The information is already present in the in the DOM, just hidden using CSS. On a first glance, it seems like the JavaScript logic is only doing CSS manipulations.

The fact that the information is hidden by CSS will not prevent you from scraping it from the source using a web scraping tool.